# Match but don't include in result using regex

Tags: c#, regex

I am trying to match a group in regex but I don't want this group to be in the final result.

For example:

**`((kl(\.)?|at)?`**`([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)`

Running the above expression on `at 12:25` should return `12:25`.

Is there any way to do this?

I tried using:

`(?:((kl(\.)?|at)? )([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)`

But that's no difference.

Then I tried

`(?<!(?:((kl(\.)?|at)? )([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)`

But that returned an empty result.

I am using the expression in C#.

Comment: `(?:...)` - non-capturing group

Comment: That returns the entire result. E.g. `at 12:25` similar to `(?:...)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A non-capturing group (not found in the match groups) is denoted as **(?:)**. So,

```
(?:(?:kl(?:\.)?|at)?([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9](:[0-5][0-9])?)
```

But you regexp seems to be wrongly structured from the outset. You don't capture the minutes.